# Update operations in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

given the following data and that i am using java with driver 3.10.1

```
    "room_price" : "500",
    "overall_price" : 10000,
    "total_paid" : 400,
    "paid" : [
            {
                    "price" : "200",
                    "Date" : ISODate("2019-10-06T00:00:00Z")
            },
            {
                    "price" : "200",
                    "Date" : ISODate("2019-10-06T00:00:00Z")
            }
    ],
```

How do i add the newly added price to the totalpaid only when the total_paid is lower than the overall_paid amount after the increment operation . noting that i have tried max() and inc() but couldn't reach any results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.update(
    {
        $expr:{
            $lt:[
                {
                    $sum:["$total_paid",345]
                },
                "$overall_price"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $addToSet:{
            "paid":{
                "price":345,
                "Date": new Date()
            }
        },
        $inc:{
            "total_paid":345
        }
    }
)
```

**Note:** Here 345 is the new price which we need to add